# memcached usage patterns

Tags: caching, architecture, amazon-web-services, memcached

I'm planning the injection of a caching system within my website, will use it in different layers (data, presentation and may be somewhere else). Being my stack LAMP and my infrastructure 100% cloud on AWS, I thought the natural choice would be Amazon Elasticache (a managed installation of memcached). But...

Surprisingly - for me - I discovered memcached completely lacks of dependency management. I don't need "advanced" stuffs like ASP.Net cache SqlDependency or FileDependency, but memcached doesn't offer an easy other-key dependency neither, something pretty useful for building a dependency tree that greatly simplify the invalidation process.

So, as I know memcached is used in many complex systems, am I missing something? Are there usage patterns that make this lack irrelevant?

thanks

UPDATE
as asked, I add some pseudo code to clarify what I mean

```
dependency = 'ROOT_KEY';
cache:set(dependency, 0, NEVER_EXPIRE);

expire = 600;
cache:set('key1', obj1, expire, dependency);
cache:set('key2', obj2, expire, dependency);
...
cache:set('keyN', objN, expire, dependency); 

//later, when I have to invalidate
cache:remove(dependency); //this will cause all keyX to be invalidated too
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are planning to interact with the cache in your application? I guess I am not following what you mean by "other-key dependency".

Comment: I've update the question with some pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example in your question, memcached (and thus Elastic Cache) does not support any sort of key metadata like you are looking for by which you could relate such keys and operate on them as a group.

I suppose if you had only a handful of different "dependencies" you could simply utilize multiple elastic cache instances, which would allow you to invalidate all items within each instance/dependency simultaneously.  This of course might end up costing you more in terms of AWS hardware costs then your would like since you can only increment your cache sizes in discrete amounts.  This also would eliminate the ability for you to do a cache lookup without knowing the dependency/instance upon which the lookup is to occur.

For what you are trying to do, you might be able to use something like memory tables in MySQL/RDS if you are looking for more of a works-out-of-the-box type of solution.  Of course you would not want to use RDS high-availibility features or point-in-time restoration, as these will break, since they require writing to disk.  You would basically need to have a standalone RDS instance doing nothing but these memory tables.

It seems none of these options however is really an exact fit for what you are looking to do, so you might need to look into either adjusting your approach (if you want to use basic AWS components), or deploying an alternate caching system on EC2.